# Relative url's wont work after url rewriting

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, relative-path

After I used url rewriting, I am having problems with relative url's.

**The Problem**

I have image in an asp.net page whose NavigateURL is ~/Images/profile.jpg which earlier(before urlrewriting) used to point correctly to the Images folder but now is being appended to the link instead. For example if the link is

`localhost/products/shoes/black`, the url for the image is now

```
localhost/products/shoes/black/~/Images/profile.jpg
```

Any ideas how do I fix it?

**UPDATE** My url rewrite rule:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
                "Products",
                "products/shoes/{color}",
                "~/produts.aspx"
                );
```

Comment: Without any usable piece of information about your rewrite rules, it will be rather difficult...

Comment: @Olaf Have a look at the rewrite rule in the question.